# Why AND two numbers to get a Boolean?

Tags: c#, vb.net, digital

I am working on a little Hardware interface project based on the Velleman k8055 board.

The example code comes in VB.Net and I'm rewriting this into C#, mostly to have a chance to step through the code and make sense of it all.

One thing has me baffled though:

At one stage they read all digital inputs and then set a checkbox based on the answer to the read digital inputs (which come back in an Integer) and then they AND this with a number:

```
i = ReadAllDigital
cbi(1).Checked = (i And 1)
cbi(2).Checked = (i And 2) \ 2
cbi(3).Checked = (i And 4) \ 4
cbi(4).Checked = (i And 8) \ 8
cbi(5).Checked = (i And 16) \ 16
```

I have not done Digital systems in a while and I understand what they are trying to do but what effect would it have to AND two numbers? Doesn't everything above 0 equate to true?

How would you translate this to C#?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers... I have clearly never had the opportunity to do any Bitwise stuff in the past... Well, I guess I can't say that anymore. ;-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you 'll have to translate it to this:

```
i & 1 == 1

i & 2 == 2

i & 4 == 4
```

etc...
This is using the bitwise AND operator.

When you use the bitwise AND operator, this operator will compare the binary representation of the two given values, and return a binary value where only those bits are set, that are also set in the two operands.

For instance, when you do this:

2 & 2

It will do this:

```
0010 & 0010
```

And this will result in:

```
 0010
 0010
&----
 0010
```

Then if you compare this result with 2 (0010), it will ofcourse return true.

Answer (score 19):

This is doing a [bitwise AND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c%28VS.71%29.aspx), not a logical AND.

Each of those basically determines whether a single bit in `i` is set, for instance:

```
5 AND 4 = 4
5 AND 2 = 0
5 AND 1 = 1
```

(Because 5 = binary 101, and 4, 2 and 1 are the decimal values of binary 100, 010 and 001 respectively.)

Comment: 5 AND 4 = 4, of course, that's why the question said (5 AND 4) \ 4

Answer (score 3):

Just to add:
It's called bitmasking
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)

A boolean only require 1 bit. In the implementation most programming language, a boolean takes more than a single bit. In PC this won't be a big waste, but embedded system usually have very limited memory space, so the waste is really significant. **To save space**, the booleans are packed together, this way a boolean variable only takes up 1 bit.

You can think of it as doing something like an **array indexing operation**, with a byte (= 8 bits) becoming like an array of 8 boolean variables, so maybe that's your answer: use an array of booleans.

Answer (score 1):

Think of this in binary e.g.

```
10101010

AND

00000010
```

yields `00000010`

i.e. not zero. Now if the first value was

```
10101000
```

you'd get

```
00000000
```

i.e. zero.

Note the further division to reduce everything to 1 or 0.

Answer (score 1):

*(i and 16) / 16* extracts the value (1 or 0) of the 5th bit.

```
1xxxx and 16 = 16 / 16 = 1
0xxxx and 16 = 0 / 16 = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

[And](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdbcfyzh(VS.71).aspx) operator performs "...bitwise conjunction on two numeric expressions", which maps to '|' in C#. The '` is an [integer division](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2hxce09y.aspx), and equivalent in C# is `/`, provided that both operands are integer types.

Answer (score 1):

The constant numbers are [masks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29) (think of them in binary). So what the code does is apply the [bitwise AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) operator on the byte and the mask and divide by the number, in order to get the bit.

For example:

```
xxxxxxxx & 00000100 = 00000x000
if x == 1
    00000x00 / 00000100 = 000000001
else if x == 0
    00000x00 / 00000100 = 000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

As said this is a bitwise AND, not a logical AND. I do see that this has been said quite a few times before me, but IMO the explanations are not so easy to understand.

I like to think of it like this:

Write up the binary numbers under each other (here I'm doing 5 and 1):

```
101
001
```

Now we need to turn this into a binary number, where all the 1's from the 1st number, that is also in the second one gets transfered, that is - in this case:

```
001
```

In this case we see it gives the same number as the 2nd number, in which this operation (in VB) returns true. Let's look at the other examples (using 5 as i):

(5 and 2)

```
101
010
----
000
```

(false)

(5 and 4)

```
101
100
---
100
```

(true)

(5 and 8)

```
0101
1000
----
0000
```

(false)

(5 and 16)

```
00101
10000
-----
00000
```

(false)

EDIT: and obviously I miss the entire point of the question - here's the translation to C#:

```
cbi[1].Checked = i & 1 == 1;
cbi[2].Checked = i & 2 == 2;
cbi[3].Checked = i & 4 == 4;
cbi[4].Checked = i & 8 == 8;
cbi[5].Checked = i & 16 == 16;
```

Answer (score 1):

In C# use the [BitArray class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray(VS.71).aspx) to directly index individual bits.

To set an individual bit *i* is straightforward:

```
b |= 1 << i;
```

To reset an individual bit *i* is a little more awkward:

```
b &= ~(1 << i);
```

Be aware that both the bitwise operators and the shift operators tend to promote everything to `int` which may unexpectedly require casting.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use hexadecimal notation when bit twiddling (e.g. 0x10 instead of 16). It makes more sense as you increase your bit depths as 0x20000 is better than 131072.